# Why diffraction of light is not evident in daily life experience as that of sound waves?

Tags: acoustics, diffraction

I know that diffraction of light takes place if the size of obstacle is comparable to the wavelength of light, but how to explain sound?
Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What specific concept do you want when you say "explain sound" and what research have you done already?

Comment: Have you compared the values of the wavelengths?

Comment: Imagine a house standing in a field of grass.  The grass does not reflect much sound, and there's nothing else near by that reflects sound.  The house is solid--made of stone--and its walls do not transmit much sound. 
 Imagine you are standing near a corner of the house, and your friend is standing just out of your sight, around the corner.  If you can hear your friend talking, then chances are, most of the sound that you are hearing was diffracted by the corner of the house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You yourself told that the diffraction of light takes place if the size of obstacle is comparable to the wavelength of light. In case of sound waves, their wavelengths are bigger than that of visible light. It is in the order of a few mm. Hence sound waves diffract easily as the obstruction can now be bigger.